# Calculating Dice coefficient for image segmentatiom

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pytorch, dice

I have created a function which calculates the Dice coefficient for the binary mask, however, I am not sure if I am doing it correctly:

```
def dice_metrics(inputs, targets, smooth=1e-8):
#inpts is the predicted mask and targets is the original mask

    #flatten label and prediction tensors
    inputs = inputs.view(-1)
    targets = targets.view(-1)

    intersection = (inputs * targets).sum()
    dice = (2.*intersection + smooth)/(inputs.sum() + targets.sum() + smooth)

    return dice
```

I am in doubt that my code above is correct because I get different values to the F1 score calculated using the `sklearn.metrics.f1_score()` function. I thought dice coefficient should be equal to the F1 score...

This is the datatypes for inputs and targets:

Data type of TARGETS: torch.float32 Min: tensor(0., device='cuda:0') Max: tensor(0.9804, device='cuda:0')

Data type of INPUTS: torch.float32 Min: tensor(0., device='cuda:0') Max: tensor(0.9804, device='cuda:0')

When using the `sklearn.metrics.f1_score()` function, the binary threshold is applied to the inputs and targets and converted to np.uint8.

The calculated dice is 0.15 but the calculated F1 score is 0.04.

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine except your ground truth should also be binary for the dice score

Comment: Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Well Im still not entirely sure why I am getting different values for dice and F1 score even when the ground truth and predicted mask are both binary...I think I will reread the sklearn documentation to find what's causing the difference.

Comment: Can you share sample tensors for input and target?

Comment: Inputs: 
tensor([[[[0.0082, 0.0032, 0.0018,  ..., 0.0021, 0.0051, 0.0118],
          [0.0032, 0.0029, 0.0020,  ..., 0.0023, 0.0043, 0.0043],
          [0.0018, 0.0018, 0.0016,  ..., 0.0017, 0.0027, 0.0029],
          ...,
          [0.0016, 0.0014, 0.0012,  ..., 0.0013, 0.0014, 0.0020],
          [0.0022, 0.0015, 0.0013,  ..., 0.0013, 0.0019, 0.0031],
          [0.0061, 0.0025, 0.0017,  ..., 0.0016, 0.0027, 0.0087]]],



target: 
tensor([[[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],

Comment: This is not very helpful since those are not the full tensors. Could you either create an example that replicates the issue with smaller tensors that could be shared in text form or alternatively, save the tensors to disk using torch.save, upload the files somewhere like google drive and share the links?

Comment: I just realized that my input is not binary. It works now that I converted the predicted mask to binary